# Relations between 'rod' and 'reed'

Tags: etymology

Do the English words 'rod' and 'reed' have a connection, given the fact that they have a semantic similarity?

Answer (score 2):

The words *rod* and *reed* look less similar when their earlier ancestors are compared.

[*Rod*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/rod#etymonline_v_15147) has no cognate in other West Germanic languages (German, Dutch), but Old English *rodd* may have descended from Old Norse *rudda*, ‘club’.

[*Reed*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/reed#etymonline_v_7476), however, comes from Old English *hreod* from a Germanic root that also yielded Old Saxon *hraid*, Old Frisian *hriad*, Middle Dutch *riet*, Low German *Reet*, Old High German *hriot*, High German *Ried*, all meaning a tall, broad-leafed marshgrass.